# Build script of package.json

Tags: javascript, package.json, parceljs

I have the below folder structure

```
-src
--module
---some.js
---another.js
--server.js
```

I am using [parceljs](https://parceljs.org/) transpile the `.js` files

The script in `package.json` looks like this

```
"build": "parcel src/*/*.js --target=node"
```

When I run `npm run build`, `server.js` is not transpiled.

If I change the build script to the below, files in `module` folder don't get transpiled

```
"build": "parcel src/*.js --target=node"
```

Any guidance so what I could transpile `.js` files in the `src` level as well as all nested files?

Comment: Does parcel take globs as inputs? If so it should be `parcel src/**/*.js --target=node` because the `**` will expand out directories and sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the both commands in a single line, using the logical operator `&&`:

```
"build": "parcel src/*.js --target=node && parcel src/*/*.js --target=node"
```

Answer (score 1):

as per @Jeremy' suggestion 
`parcel src/**/*.js --target=node`